# Queue messages for async processing

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

Im receiving list of messages asynchronously from server push api. I need to do some long running work for each messages. Currently im using async task for that.

In my current implementation in creating new async task every time I receive messages. I have noticed that on older devices, im running like five async task in same time (I think they are queued). This does not sound very efficient for mew.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    // Called when server pushes new messages
    private void messagesReceived(List<MyMessage> newMessages) {
        new MyMessageProcessorAsyncTask(newMessages) {
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(List<MyProcessedMessage> messages) {
                // Update ui
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

What is typically the best way to handle this kind of queue for async processing and how many async operations I should run in same time?

Comment: Did you look into using an `IntentService`? It will queue your tasks, run them one at a time, and you can provide a `LocalBroadcastReceiver` to update UI.

Comment: check rxjava library. you can write in functional and reactive programming paradigm.